# GET requests work but POST requests 404 in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a project which uses MVC 5 and Web API 2.  Locally, both HTTP GET and POST requests to the Web API controller are working.  When the website is published and deployed to an external environment, the GET requests still work, but the POST requests result in a 404.

Here's my API controller:

```
public class ExampleApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetRoles")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRoles([FromBody] string userName)
    {
        // ...
        return Json(response);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUsers")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        // ...
        return response;
    }
}
```

Here's my `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Web API default route",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: null
        );
    }
}
```

Here's my `Global.asax` file:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Some other notes:

- I've verified that the POST request that the client is making is formatted correctly.
- I added the following code to the `Web.config`:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  ```
- The environment I'm deploying my application out to has a subdomain which requires authentication (e.g. the URL looks something like `http://qa.example.com`).  I am testing using (for instance) `http://username:password@qa.example.com/GetUsers`.
- My controller is not using the `RoutePrefix` attribute.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try disabling the GET controller action and then retry the POST action. Tell us if that worked.

Comment: @OrelEraki I commented out the GET controller action, but the POST request still 404s.

Comment: Try renaming the method and attribute of `GetUsers` to `PostUsers` (While the get method still commented).

Comment: ***GetRoles*** method name is really confusing. Besides that how do you post data to ***Post*** action method.

Comment: @OrelEraki My actual method name is totally different and does not contain "Get" or "Post".  This is just a contrived example.

Comment: @alex, Nevertheless try it anyhow as i suggested.

Comment: @alex, add `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in your web.config to check for a better error message. Several users reported that missing assemblies after deployment can cause this problem.

Comment: @OrelEraki As far as I'm aware, the name of the method shouldn't matter.   If it was called "GetPostPutDeleteRoles", the routing should still work.

Comment: @Nkosi It's something like `POST http://qa.example.com/GetRoles` with a string in the content body.

Comment: @alex, ok. use something like fiddler and inspect the request being sent to the endpoint. show an example of the request. could be that the payload is malformed. You have  the `FromBody` parameter attribute. used to extract simple type from complex model in body. check out [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: You should also look into checking your `system.web/handlers` in web.config on the host to make sure that it allows POST verb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved - not super helpful for future readers, but the issue was related to a third-party security client on the server-side specifically blocking the request.  [Juliano's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004909/get-requests-work-but-post-requests-404-in-web-api-2?noredirect=1#comment67288109_40004909) helped me in that direction of realizing this.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest use web API documentation (help page) or swagger to check your web api method actual url and parameter. you must missing something.

few day back I've face similar problem (post method working on local but not working on QA env.) but that time I was getting 405 error